# jQuery UI Slider: Allow handles to cross over

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, uislider, rangeslider

I am using a range slider on the following webpage http://www.mattpealing.co.uk/_concept/brdcr/calc/patient-static.html (see 'Day & Night Shift')

I have customised it like so, so that it works in hours and minutes (15 minute increments):

```
$(function() {
    $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 1439,
        values: [ 0, 1000 ],
        step: 15,
        slide: function(e, ui) {
            var hoursDay = Math.floor(ui.values[0] / 60);
            var minutesDay = ui.values[0] - (hoursDay * 60);

            var hoursNight = Math.floor(ui.values[1] / 60);
            var minutesNight = ui.values[1] - (hoursNight * 60);

            if(hoursDay.toString().length == 1) hoursDay = '0' + hoursDay;
            if(minutesDay.toString().length == 1) minutesDay = '0' + minutesDay;

            if(hoursNight.toString().length == 1) hoursNight = '0' + hoursNight;
            if(minutesNight.toString().length == 1) minutesNight = '0' + minutesNight;

            $('.time-day').text(hoursDay+':'+minutesDay);
            $('.time-night').text(hoursNight+':'+minutesNight);
        }
    });
});
```

What I need to do now is to set it so that the handles can overlap. This way it will allow the user to specify a shift of, say, 20:00–04:00. Also when the handles overlap, the highlighted blue bar should reflect it instead of appearing in the middle of the handles

Currently this is not possible.

I can't even think of where to start in order to achieve this, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need this? If you begin dragging the left handle and it moves passed the right handle you would need to change the icons within the handles, and also it would massively complicate any logic used to read the values/range selected.

Comment: I guess I know what you try to achieve. Googled a bit around but haven't found something yet. Maybe you want to change it from a single slider to 2x datetimepicker fields, would be much easier, but doesn't look that great.

Answer (score 0):

You can invert your range slider with some tricks. This is a sample with a click event :
**HTML**

```
<div id="slider-range"></div>

<div class="from time-day"></div>
<div class="to time-night"></div>

<button>Invert</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('button').click(function() {
        $('#slider-range, #slider-range .ui-slider-range').toggleClass('ui-widget-header ui-widget-content');
        var timeFrom = $(".from").text();
        var timeTo = $(".to").text();
        $(".from").html(timeTo).toggleClass("time-day").toggleClass("time-night");
        $(".to").html(timeFrom).toggleClass("time-night").toggleClass("time-day");
    });

    $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 1439,
        values: [ 0, 1000 ],
        step: 15,
        slide: function(e, ui) {
            var hoursDay = Math.floor(ui.values[0] / 60);
            var minutesDay = ui.values[0] - (hoursDay * 60);

            var hoursNight = Math.floor(ui.values[1] / 60);
            var minutesNight = ui.values[1] - (hoursNight * 60);

            if(hoursDay.toString().length == 1) hoursDay = '0' + hoursDay;
            if(minutesDay.toString().length == 1) minutesDay = '0' + minutesDay;

            if(hoursNight.toString().length == 1) hoursNight = '0' + hoursNight;
            if(minutesNight.toString().length == 1) minutesNight = '0' + minutesNight;

            $('.time-day').text(hoursDay+':'+minutesDay);
            $('.time-night').text(hoursNight+':'+minutesNight);
        }
    });
});
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8md1fds0/)

I do not have time to go further but you can adapt this code with another piece of code to detect an overlap like this :

```
  $( "#slider-range" ).bind( "slide", function(event, ui) {
      var values = $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "option", "values" );
      if (ui.values[0] >= ui.values[1]) {
            console.log("overlap");
      }
  });
```

Hope it helped.